# Build in Android Studio 3.0.0 - Gradle 3.0.0-beta5

Tags: android, gradle, build

I'm in Android Studio 3.0.0 / gradle-3.0.0-beta5. App depends on several libraries (kotlin/java). Built my me.

I've a problem when I build my application. When I use this command : 
`./gradlew clean lint assemble`, I've got an error like this :

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForPreprodRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process

Do you know what it means ?

Thx.

When I use --debug I had this informations @bvarga :

> 10:09:12.165 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   10:09:12.165 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   10:09:12.165 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
>   10:09:12.165 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForPreprodRelease'.
>   10:09:12.165 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
>   10:09:12.165 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   10:09:12.165 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
>   10:09:12.166 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForPreprodRelease'.
>   10:09:12.166 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>   10:09:12.166 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>   10:09:12.166 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipCachedTaskExecuter.execute(SkipCachedTaskExecuter.java:106)
>   10:09:12.166 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
>   10:09:12.166 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>   10:09:12.166 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:60)
>   10:09:12.166 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>   10:09:12.166 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2112.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
>   10:09:12.167 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 32 more
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:222)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 47 more
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.dexInProcess(DexByteCodeConverter.java:178)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.runDexer(DexByteCodeConverter.java:150)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.convertByteCode(DexByteCodeConverter.java:135)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:213)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 50 more
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.dexInProcess(DexByteCodeConverter.java:176)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 53 more
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.DexWrapper$DexProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(DexWrapper.java:117)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.lambda$dexInProcess$0(DexByteCodeConverter.java:171)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   10:09:12.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 1 more

Comment: In my project I had duplicate classes. But only switching to `3.0.0-beta2` produced useful error message.

Comment: Use -S -d switches for more information

Comment: I tried, but at one point, the build goes round and does not continue

Comment: I had my report with debug @bvarga